# How to OpenWebConfiguration with physical path?

Tags: c#-3.0, web-config, webconfigurationmanager, virtual-path

I have a win form that creates a site in IIS7.
One function needs to open the web.config file and make a few updates. (connection string, smtp, impersonation)

However I do not have the virtual path, just the physical path.

Is there any way I can still use WebConfigurationManager?

I need to use it's ability to find section and read/write.

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You will have to map the physicalPath to a virtualPath. Here is how you would do that.

```
using System.Web.Configuration;  //Reference the System.Web DLL (project needs to be using .Net 4.0 full, not client framework)

public static Configuration OpenConfigFile(string configPath)
{
    var configFile = new FileInfo(configPath);
    var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName, true, configFile.Name);
    var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
    wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
    return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
}
```

Comment: For me, I have to use `public static System.Configuration.Configuration OpenConfigFile(string configPath)`.

Answer (score 10):

Vadim's answer worked great on our dev server, but bombed out on our live server with the following message:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: site
```

To correct this, I found another overload for `WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration` that takes the IIS website name as the third parameter.  The result is as follows:

```
public static Configuration OpenConfigFile(string configPath)
{
    var configFile = new FileInfo(configPath);
    var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configFile.DirectoryName, true, configFile.Name);
    var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
    wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
    return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/", "iis_website_name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vadim's answer was exactly what I needed, but I came across the same issue as Kieth, and his solution did the trick!

I thought I'd add though, that the IIS Website name can be [retrieved by calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654797/get-iis-site-name-from-for-an-asp-net-website):

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
```

Also, cjbarth's code included a tidy solution for those testing in environments where the location of wwwroot and Web.config can vary:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
```

So with these in mind another slight improvement on Vadim's function would read:

```
    public static Configuration GetWebConfig() {
        var webConfigFile = new FileInfo("Web.config");
        var wwwRootPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
        var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(wwwRootPath, true, webConfigFile.Name);
        var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
        wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
        var siteName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
        return WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/", siteName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using Powershell.

```
$file = "D:\Applications\XXX\Private\XXX\XXXX\web.config"

 

$configurationAssembly = "System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
[Void] [Reflection.Assembly]::Load($configurationAssembly)

 
$filepath = New-Object System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationFileMap
$filepath.ExeConfigFileName = $file
$configuration = [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager]::OpenMappedExeConfiguration($filepath,0)
$section = $configuration.GetSection("appSettings")



Write-Host "Set the Protection Provider"

 

if (-not $section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
    $section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
    $configuration.Save()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Vadim's answer, I found what he wrote didn't exactly work for my situation, so I used this instead:

```
Dim connectionSettings As New ConnectionStringSettings("mySQLite", ConnectionStringHelper.MyConnectionString)

Dim dummyVirtualPath As String = "/MyApp"
Dim virtualDirMap = New VirtualDirectoryMapping(Server.MapPath("~"), True)
Dim webConfigFileMap = New WebConfigurationFileMap()
webConfigFileMap.VirtualDirectories.Add(dummyVirtualPath, virtualDirMap)
Dim mappedConfigFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(webConfigFileMap, dummyVirtualPath)

Dim config As System.Configuration.Configuration = mappedConfigFile WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Server.MapPath("~") & "/")
Dim csSection As ConnectionStringsSection = config.ConnectionStrings

If csSection.ConnectionStrings("mySQLite") IsNot Nothing AndAlso csSection.ConnectionStrings("mySQLite").ConnectionString <> connectionSettings.ConnectionString Then
    csSection.ConnectionStrings("mySQLite").ConnectionString = connectionSettings.ConnectionString
    config.Save()
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(csSection.SectionInformation.Name)
End If
```

In case anyone else is trying what I'm trying and finds this, the purpose of my doing this was to get `SimpleMembershipProvider`, which inherits from `ExtendedMembershipProvider`, to work with SQLite. To do that, I created the tables manually per this link: [SimpleMembershipProvider in MVC4](http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/11/10/simplemembershipprovider-in-mvc4-for-mysql-oracle-and-more-with-llblgen/), and then used this command in my `Global.asax` file's `Application_Start` routine:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(ConnectionStringHelper.MyConnectionString, "System.Data.SQLite", "Users", "UserID", "Email", False)
```

Which it turns out didn't require me to actually re-write my web.config file at all. (There were also a lot of web.config changes I had to do, but that is even more out of the scope of this question.)