# How to read Web.config file that located on disk

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

How can I read Web.config file that located on my local computer.
I try to use

```
var settings=WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(@"C:\myFolder...\Web.config").AppSettings;
```

but I have exception: 
"The relative virtual path 'C:/myFolder/.../Web.config' is not allowed here."

Comment: Is this web config is a part of your solution or project?

Comment: Seems to be similiar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368748/how-to-openwebconfiguration-with-physical-path