# Web API 2: HttpServer in-memory server and App/Web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, enterprise-library, httpserver

For unit testing, I'm running an in-memory server using the `System.Web.Http.HttpServer` class.  It chokes when attempting to instantiate Enterprise Library objects, because Enterprise Library (v5.0.414.0) is configured in the XML configuration file `App.config`, which isn't being read.

Is it possible to read in the `.config` file, or am I forced to start a local server (e.g. `WcfSvcHost.exe`)?

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to load the configuration thusly (from [How to OpenWebConfiguration with physical path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368748/how-to-openwebconfiguration-with-physical-path)):

```
var wcfm = new System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationFileMap();
var vdm = new System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping( @"C:\MyPath\", true, "App.config" );
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add( "/", vdm );
var cfg = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration( wcfm, "/" );
```

However, I don't know of any straightforward way to pass that data to the `HttpServer` object (`cfg` is a `Configuration` type, apparently of no relation to the `HttpConfiguration` type found in `HttpServer` constructors).

I wanted to avoid implementing an IISExpress solution, but it looks as though I'm forced to go that route in order to support Enterprise Library 5 lameness.

Comment: Which unit testing environment are you using?

Comment: MS.VS.TestTools.UnitTesting with VSTest, the standard in Visual Studio.

Comment: Note that I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368748/how-to-openwebconfiguration-with-physical-path, which works for loading the XML file, but presumably a `System.Configuration.Configuration` object is incompatible with the `HttpServer` type.  I'm looking for a solution that works for the in-memory `HttpServer`.

Comment: IIS Express might be another option.

Comment: I have Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting tests which test  components that rely on settings in the .config file.  It's definitely reading the app.config.

Comment: Are you using the in-memory server from [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Testing/) package? Also have you added the app.config file to your test project?

Comment: @Mick, as I wrote, I can read App.config but how do apply the configuration to an object of type System.Web.Http.HttpServer?

Comment: @Anish, no, as I wrote, I'm using System.Web.Http.HttpServer.  Does Microsoft.Owin.Testing supply a means of in-memory server testing with support for XML configuration files?  (And yes, App.config is part of the unit testing project.)

Comment: Perhaps this helps .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851558/testing-route-configuration-in-asp-net-webapi

Comment: @MiloDC Yes [Microsoft.Owin.Testing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Testing/) supplies a means of in-memory server testing and odes support XML configuration files. I use it and read from `App.config` and `Web.config` all of the time. The issue you are having maybe down to your test runner.

Comment: @Anish, I will give Owin.Testing a serious look ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/26/unit-testing-owin-applications-using-testserver.aspx ).  That might be the way to go, hopefully it will be something that I can implement quickly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the in-memory HttpServer class works fine; no need for the Owin stuff.  I just needed to have references to a few Enterprise Library assemblies in my unit test project *as well as* my Web API 2 project.

Fusion logging saved the day again.  Such a great way to debug obscure library resolution errors.  ( http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx )