# Is there an RoleInstanceId equivilent on Azure Websites?

Tags: azure

I'm looking for the equivalent of an Azure RoleInstanceId, but on an Azure Website (as opposed to an Azure Web Role).  I've looked extensively for such a thing, but to no avail.  I even deployed a "test" website to display all of the Environment Variables on the Azure Website, but there didn't appear to be a useful variable in the set.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated!

BTW, in case you're interested in why I would want such a thing, I'm trying to implement an advanced version of the Steve Marx's excellent [Scalable Counters with Windows Azure](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-43-Scalable-Counters-with-Windows-Azure)...

Answer (score 0):

```
Request.ServerVariables[ "INSTANCE_ID" ]
```

[Get IIS site id from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855176/get-iis-site-id-from-a-website)

Would give you IIS site Id .. Might work as an identify. Other than hard coding in configuration file.

That should give you a unique id then of inputting a id for each row of the counter. 
Worst case would be just use Guid and generate it each time.

This would then make sure you counter would be good.

Hths,

James

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, I tried it with two separate instances, but each returns the same value.